# How can I solve this martingale problem with markov chains?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be a Markov Chain with finite state space $E \subset \mathbb{R}$.  Suppose that the chain has two absorbent states $A = \{i,j\}$ and the other states are transient.  Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $(g(X_n))_{n \ge 0}$ is martingale.

Prove that the absorption probabilities $\rho_{ki}, \rho_{kj}$ where $k \in E \setminus A$ satisfy the system of equations:
$$
\begin{split}
g(k) &= g(i) \rho_{ki} &+ g(j)\rho_{kj}\\
1 &= \rho_{ki}         &+ \rho_{kj}
\end{split}
$$
for all $k \in E \setminus A$.